# Android Studio al desplegar no crea el acceso directo

Tags: android

Tengo un Motorola E4 Plus, Android 7.1.1 realice un hola mundo para login de facebook con Android Studio Sdk 26 compatible con Android 4.2 en adelante.

Realice varios despliegues y de pronto desapareció el icono de la aplicación tanto del escritorio como de la sección de aplicaciones. Al desplegar por Android Studio la aplicación se ejecuta, sin embargo yendo por configuración>aplicaciones me indica que no hay un vinculo directo.

He des instalado y vuelto a instalar desde cero, también creé una nueva aplicación y pase mi código al desplegar hace exactamente lo mismo.

Como puedo reparar el acceso directo y/o Configuración de la aplicación para que genere el icono al desplegar?

---

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Todo funciona hasta que agrego a la vista el botón de login de facebook

En gradle.build de la aplicación tengo esta dependencia
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
y en gradle.build del proyecto agrego a repositories
mavenCentral()
y a allprojects{ repositories { 
mavenCentral()

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` de tu aplicación, debes asegurar agregar un icono mediante la propiedad [`android:icon`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), ya sea uno que se encuentre en el directorio `/drawable` o `/mipmap`, por ejemplo:

```
  <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/my_icon"
        ...
        ...
```

Si no defines la propiedad no aparecerá el icono ya que no existe un icono default para la aplicación.

Comment: El desarrollo desde mi casa en mi trabajo no tengo acceso en la noche agrego el Manifest y pruebo de antemano gracias.

Comment: @Rubens , excelente, para tener más información agrega también tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml , saludos.

Comment: Si tengo el icono.muchas gracias